# How to debug E_FAIL from CommandBars.ExecuteMso?

Tags: c#, ms-office, powerpoint, office-interop, office-addins

While using my PowerPoint Add-in, some users get the following exception:
`Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.`
It happens when trying to create a new presentation with `Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("FileNew")`, which is supposed to open the backstage tab.

**Complications:**

1. The backstage is supported for the user (on PowerPoint 2016)
2. Official Microsoft documentation states only the return of `E_FAIL` in case of failure, giving no further clues for [C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core._commandbars.executemso.aspx) as well as for [VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/office-shared-vba/articles/commandbars-executemso-method-office?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
3. I cannot reproduce the problem on any of the machines available to me

How can I debug and try to prevent this exception?

Comment: Any chance you can take a look at the Event Viewer of the affected user's PC? There may be some information there, but cannot guarantee so

Comment: Probably not, but I will try. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: It is a documented error code: "E_Fail for controls that are not enabled or not visible".  So you must assume that Powerpoint is in a state that does not allow creating a new document, take appropriate counter-measures in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Hans Passant who restated the error code "E_Fail for controls that are not **enabled** or not **visible**", I double checked `CommandBars` object to find out that there are two methods:

1. Application.CommandBars.GetEnabledMso(*CommandName*)
2. Application.CommandBars.GetVisibleMso(*CommandName*)

So I use the first one to check whether the command is enabled before executing it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `ActivateTabMso` of the `IRibbonUI` interface if you want to activate a particular built-in tab. Then you will be able to use the `ExecuteMso` method.

You can read more about that in the [Ribbon Extensibility in Office 2010: Tab Activation and Auto-Scaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee691834(v=office.14))